# Android Life Cycle - Data not Reloading

Tags: android, android-listview, android-lifecycle

I am stuck with trying to figure out what is causing my app to lose data in two `ListView`s, one in each of two tabs, both of which are `ListFragment`s. The `ListView`s are empty randomly on a phone when you bring the app to the forefront.

I'm guessing I'm missing something with how data is to be restored when bringing back up the application. Generally the app restores and data in both tabs are there.

However, only on a real phone it seems, the data will be gone from the `ListView`s but I cannot find a reproducible pattern.

I've used DDMS to simulate a garbage collection in many combinations and I can't reproduce the loss of data. Here is how I'm dealing with the life cycle, simplified and basically total pseudo code.

I've looked over the lifecycle structure and thought I had it working.

Am I refreshing incorrectly?

**Main activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // I don't refresh here
        // add both tabs to the tab adapter
    }

    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart(); 
        reloadTab1();
        reloadTab2();
    }
}
```

**Tab 1**

```
public class MyTab1 extends ListFragment {
    static MyTab1Adapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<MyObject> mItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain state
        setRetainInstance(true);
        reloadTab1(getActivity());
    }

    public void reloadTab1(Context context) {
        mItems = updateItems();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new MyTab1Adapter(context, R.layout.tab1, mItems);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }           
        else {
            mAdapter.setNewList(mItems);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Tab 2**

```
public class MyTab2 extends ListFragment {
    static MyTab2Adapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<MyObject> mItems;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain state
        setRetainInstance(true);
        reloadTab2(getActivity());
    }

    public void reloadTab2(Context context) {
        mItems = updateItems();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new MyTab2Adapter(context, R.layout.tab2, mItems);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }           
        else {
            mAdapter.setNewList(mItems);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a typo I guess, but `onRestart` and calling `super.onResume()`?

Comment: I actually just noticed that and it was a bug in my app. Maybe that will fix it, we will see. Good catch

Comment: If you're using `onRestart`, that callback will not be called unless the activity was killed while being in the background. `onResume` will be called each time so the fragments should be refresh each time you come back to the activity.

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the number of calls to getView as I possibly can. I'll spend some time tonight trying to see if I can get acceptable results from `onResume`. Thank you for taking an interest in my question

Comment: I don't know how do you plan to reduce the number of `getView` calls. . If you call `notifyDataSetChanged` the `getView` methods will be called because the adapter knows his data has changed. A small optimization would be to somehow see if the data has really changed(but this depends on your implementation) and only then call `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'm referring to trying to reduce the number of refreshes and onResume is called far more often than necessary in my application. It looks like correcting the typo and changing `super.onResume()` to `super.onRestart()` fixed the issue. If you can put an answer below suggesting I fix that typo, I'll accept it since that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a small typo in your code, you used the `onRestart` callback but called the `onResume` mthod from the super class instead of `super.onRestart();`.